# How to get the sum in three tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: DefMatiere which holds the names of the items and a table ingredient which holds the used quantites and StockData which holds the quantities bought and their values.

I wrote this query for getting the names of items and quantities used and bought and the the sums paid.

```
SELECT dm.nom, SUM(IF(dm.id=ig.matid, ig.qty, 0)) AS used,
SUM(DISTINCT IF(dm.id=sd.matid ,sd.quantite,0)) AS achete, 
SUM(DISTINCT IF(dm.id=sd.matid ,sd.montant*(1+(sd.tvaval/100)) ,0)) AS val, 
(SUM(DISTINCT IF(dm.id=sd.matid ,sd.quantite,0))- SUM(IF(dm.id=ig.matid, ig.qty, 0))) AS restant
FROM DefMatiere AS dm 
LEFT JOIN ingredient AS ig ON ig.matid=dm.id 
LEFT JOIN StockData AS sd on sd.matid = dm.id 
WHERE dm.type = 1 GROUP BY dm.nom
```

This gives what I want but it seems to be a very long annoyant roman.

Is it possible to use the aliases for making those calculations LIKE achete - val AS restant

Because I want to add too val/achete*used val/achete*restant in this case my query becomes like the LORD of the RINGS 6 volumes.

Or I must continue to write my roman ? Any help will teach me

[EDIT]

However after entering some more datas I saw this query is not correct.

Because if there is more then one row with same matid in StockData the result that I get for used is doubled or tripled depending on number of rows.

[HERE](http://www.turcguide.com/stack/results.jpg) the results of the query and the solution I've found

And [HERE](http://www.turcguide.com/stack/proc.txt) is how I resolved. But I could not find a suitable query.

Comment: You want aliases as variables which is not possible.

Comment: Maybe something like: SELECT @used=SUM(IF(dm.id=ig.matid, ig.qty, 0)) FROM table

Comment: As long as it executes quickly, that's the only thing to worry about

Comment: I tried aliases and saw it's not possible, and I see that I must continue to write my roman. How ever I will try what's advised by Mihai. I will perhaps shorten the rest of my calculations if it works

Comment: what Mihai said but i think you need to set using something like `@used:=SUM(IF ....`

Comment: What do you mean by "roman"?  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+is+a+sql+roman

Comment: @my username was hijacked here I used it for the length of the code I will use. I solved it. It's in my second link. But I know it can be resolved by few lines of SQL. I will do it later when I will discover the mystery of SQL

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is relatively straightforward I think, but not that simple that I want to sit and write the SQL for you.

But since you asked to be taught, which I think is good, here is what I think will help you the most in the long term:

I think the best way to write SQL (and to learn to write SQL) is not from scratch but rather with a more powerful graphical SQL tool with a wizard.  I use  Microsoft Access 2003 but there are many other SQL tools available.  On a tool like that you can easily set up your models and link and query and sum to your heart's delight.

When I'm building difficult queries in php I often first model the queries in the SQL graphical user interface and then once I have the totals like I want them, I save the SQL produced and plug it into php.

Comment: My objective when I send this question is not that someone write the SQL for me but show a way as Mihai has done. I tried what he advised it's not working. I've already wrote my roman it's working. My goal is if there is way to shorten my roman. That's all.